# Como crear una variable de sesión con laravel?

Tags: laravel

Laravel permite usar el `Auth::user()->id` pero que pasa si existen varios roles y quiero realizar mi lógica apartir de un valor pk de otras tablas y no exclusivamente del `Auth::user()->id`.

Por ejemplo:
En el caso que se logea un usuario  profesor, me gustaría obtener el id de la tabla profesores como una variable de sesión.

¿como se realiza esto en laravel?

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que has investigado, de paso te recomiendo leer [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para almacenar datos en la sesión, normalmente se utiliza el método put o el ayudante de sesión:

```
// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

// Via the global helper...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

un ejemplo

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $value = $request->session()->get('key');

        //AQUI COLOCAS TU VARIABLE

        $request->session()->put('key', 'value');
    }
}
```

Más info en : [sesión](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session)